# Not able to scan below barcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have integrated red laser for barcode scanning in my application. But found out that its is not able to scan one barcode.Do anybody have idea of any altenative to red laser or how to support scanning of below barcode.[image]

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Zbar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/index.html) sample app was able to read your barcode (see iPhone Developers section for the downloading link)